# EBS Backed Root Partition Too Small - How Do I use full EBS capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I started a new instance using debian-jessie-amd64-hvm-2015-04-25-23-22-ebs (ami-0d5b6c3d) and an 80GB EBS as the root volume. Here's the problem I am seeing:

```
admin@ip-xxxxxx:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.3G  6.1G  17% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  4.3M  196M   3% /run
tmpfs           500M     0  500M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           500M     0  500M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

admin@ip-xxxxxxx:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  80G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

Why does it even do this? It's silly to default me to 8GB and then not give me an easy way to resize the partition. Watch this:

```
admin@ip-xxxxx:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
The filesystem is already 2096128 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I've seen some guides online but they don't seem to work for me. I tried taking a snapshot and started a secondary instance with a different(new) primary ebs. Then I attached my vole created from the snapshot, however it kept booting into the snapshot volume, not the new one I created for that instance.

First, I want to know is this even possible - and more importantly, how?

My only reservations are, if they make me jump through this many hoops to get this setup, is there a better way to manage the data growth on my site? Would it be better to just have a small root ebs, and then add another volume for the MySQL data dir and site uploads? Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an EBS volume from an EBS snapshot that is bigger than the original EBS snapshot (like what you're doing), the file-system held on that volume will still report the original size.

It's standard behaviour and you must use `resize2fs` in order to expand the file-system to occupy the entire new size volume.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

This is because AWS knows about EBS volumes as data blocks; it does not know about the file-systems stored. For example, AWS does not know that your file-system is ext3, ext4, xfs, or ntfs. It does not know that you want your partition to take the entire volume or if you want to add a new partition. These are up to you to decide and manage yourself.

As for your follow-up question, it's probably best to put your data on a secondary volume and mount it within your file-system. This way, you can add space by mounting more volumes and/or unmounting existing volumes.